# My Bootstrap Website Issue with Body on Smart Phone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

A while ago I created www.readourlips.org and it looked great on phone and computer. But now, the index.html page is narrow when viewed on an iPhone (at least mine) because the body color is visible (see photo)
Does anyone know why this would suddenly change? It's not essential but the site doesn't look great anymore on a phone (only home page though)
Thank you all,

website is http://readourlips.org

David[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map at the bottom of the homepage is pushing the website to the right side, make the map have a width=100% and this will fix it

Take out the width attribute on the iframe tag, and put the width=100% as inline css